# JavaFX - font smoothing/anti-aliasing

Tags: java, css, javafx, fonts

How could I use aa/smoothing to get the following result(taken out from photoshop, where aa was set to "strong"):

[image: The look I want to achieve(font using smoothing/aa)]

I set the same settings in my JavaFX project, however the aa/smoothing is missing. So it looks like this:

[image: The look right now(font without smoothing/aa)]

Due to googled I found [FoundSmoothing](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/text/FontSmoothingType.html) in JavaFX, however this doesn´t work at all(it has no effect).

I want to achieve the result in the first screenshot(aa/smoothing on the font):

The following styling is what I used:

```
btn.setStyle("-fx-background-color:#427ff1; -fx-font: 14px Roboto-Regular; -fx-text-fill: white;");
```

Any ideas how to achieve that(I want the basic google font(Roboto-Sans) look, shown in the first screenshot).

Thanks :)